# VSCode Git via Remote-SSH

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code

I have a VMWare Fusion 11.5 running which holds my repos. I prefer to run my tools on the Mac (Azure SQL Studio, VSCode etc) and not on the VM so I have setup VSCode to SSH to the VM machine.

Everything works, updating the code git status, add and commit however when I try to git pull/push from bitbucket nothing happens, no error message no time out nothing.

SSH is password based i think (it asks me for my password when I try to connect to the VM via SSH).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If it asks for a *password* (the password of the remote account) and not a *passphrase*, that means the public key was not properly registered to the VMWare remote machine, at `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Start by adding your MacOS `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` content to the remote user `~/.ssh/authrized_keys` file.

Comment: I have failed to make VSCode connect via private-public key pair, I have followed the the instructions on the VSCode website in regards to the Remote-SSH.

However using the keys to connect is not my problem (I do not really have a problem having to enter a password when I connect) unless I need to connect via a key pari for git push / pull to work. But why would that be the case?

Comment: If it is a public repo, it won't be the case for pulling. But pushing is generally linked to authentication first.

Comment: it is not public, usually i get asked password to push and pull but that shouldn't have anything to do with my shh authentication to the VM. Does it mean that it expects authentication to bitbucket but the request for my repo password is not coming through to the ssh terminal?

Comment: @user3829059 If your SSH private key is not protected by a passphrase, and it still asks for a *password*, that means it (the remote side) does not find your public key and defaults to username/password.

Comment: Yes I understand this. But is a key/passphrase necessary for git push/pull?

Comment: @user3829059 Yes at least for push (not pull for public repo)

Comment: ok thank you I will try to set it up again and post with the results.

Comment: So this hasn't actually done anything , I have managed to use a pubkey to authenticate ssh sessions from VSCode to VM windows, however pull and push still do not work.